# generic variable Names

Tags: c#, variables

I have a string variable which has the value that the user taps. I need to make another variable which its name will be the string's value.
How do / can I do that?

Comment: You don't. Search for "C# dictionary tutorial" - this is a rather common task (to deal with Key/Value or "Map" collections), sorry for all the down-votes :(

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @user2246674, good catch.  Flesh out your comment, perhaps with a link to the `Dictionary<TK,TV>` class and submit it as an answer.

Comment: Please... tell me why you would possibly consider doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do that: the closest you can get is a `Dictionary<string,object>` (you can replace the `object` with some other type). Using this dictionary you would be able to create associations between strings (known as "keys") and values stored in the dictionary.

```
IDictionary<string,object> variables = new Dictionary<string,object>();
string varName = "hello";
variables[varName] = "world";
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Value: {1}", varName, variables[varName]);
```